Azure FunctionApp timer does not trigger?
I have an Azure FunctionApp with a timer trigger like this:
// 6 minutes after the hour every day
[TimerTrigger("0 6 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,        

It was working fine for many months, but recently I had to update some logic in the code and re-published it.
Now it does not trigger anymore.
I tried to do some troubleshooting in the Azure portal and found this issue:

The strange is that the above error does not make any sense to me and seems not to be related to my code at all. The column name referred (AppCommandLine) is not related to my code. The message seems to indicate an error in the Function App service as it looks to me.
What could be the issue?

How strange! Please could you copy the log message and paste it into a code block in the question, in case the image hosting is removed in future? This will help the question stay useful to the community.

The strange error in the Azure portal went away by itself, so I guess it was an error in the service itself.
